# How to check whether an #id exists using phpquery? .length?

Tags: exists, phpquery

How to check whether an #id exists using phpquery?

*jQuery:*

```
if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
    // element exist
}
```

[phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Manual)
To check whether an .class exists works by using ->hasClass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(pq("#mydiv")->length) {
  // element exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be the way you ask this, but isn't this a case of mixing up ID's and classes? # searches for an ID, if you want an array with classes you'll need $`(".mydiv")`...